# Android DialogFragment - MultiChoice Dialog checkboxes do not update / require two clicks

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I think this has only started happening with recent Android API(s), but the problem is that the first time you try to select a checkbox in a MultiChoice Dialog, it requires an additional click for the UI to update.

I'm pretty sure it's due to an Android bug as my code is very simple.

After a lot of experimenting, I've found the answer so will share it below...

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part of the solution was to get the `View` object. Once you have the `View`, you can `invalidate()` it in order to update the UI of the checkboxes.

Here is the essentials from my `DialogFragment` subclass:

```
public class MyMultiChoiceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private View mView = null;

    @Override @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(
            cursor,
            isCheckedColumn
            labelColumn
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                // Handle the checkbox de/selection

                /*
                 * The problem is that, despite onClick being called (with the correct parameter values), the
                 * checkbox ticks were not updating on the UI.
                 * Solution is to invalidate/redraw the layout so the checkboxes also update visually
                 */
                mView.invalidate();
                mView.forceLayout(); // Following tests, this line is also required.

            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        /*
         * This seems to be the only way to get the view.
         * Save it in an instance variable so we can access it within onClick()
         */
        mView = dialog.getListView();

        return dialog;
    }    

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mView = null; // Clean up / prevent memory leak - necessary?
    }

}
```